# Java - how to check phone operator by phone number

Tags: java, phone-number

Is there possibility to find out the operator name by phone number? Of course it's about the mobile phone numbers. Country is easy because of the prefix. But what about the operators?

Comment: Are you developing for android?

Comment: I'm thinking about develop it for android and web also.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: ok maybe I ask in a wrong way. I'm thinking if there is some way to write an API for such purpose. I best know java that's way I ask this question with this particular language.

Answer (score 1):

For android apps you can look into [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

So you can have something like this

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Comment: Thanks I look forward for that it looks promising

Comment: You're welcome! do mark it as accepted if it can be of any help. So further readers can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't how it's look like in every country, but in my country ( Poland ) it's imposible because the costumers can change the operator and keep old phone number.

Comment: heh I'm trying to find it out actually in PL :). I think there need to be some mechanism. I added new sim card (different operator) to my android phone. After that whenever I tried to dial phone number that belongs to the same operator as that sim, android automatically choses that sim for me... Maybe coincident, but I think there is some possibility :)

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible logically. Think of scenario where portability from one operator to another is viable keeping the same number

Comment: Yes that's true and that's why I started to think about that. In google play store there are some apps that are trying to do so, but they doesn't work...

Comment: Ok I've done some research and it seems that indeed it's impossible to get the info about external phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's probablity to read information about operator from sim card, on every sim card it's write information about country and operator:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code
but in that case you have to have physical access to sim card. So your app maybe can find the operator of phone that it's runing on, but it's still imposible to find operator with only phone number, unless you have acces to operators databeses of course ;)